# Dart: getElementsByClassName returns a 0 element list but the data is there

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm writing a function that will parse certain websites and fetch data from there, which will be used to create instances of a class. I'm able to successfully extract the data when it is retrieved using the getElementById() function, but for some reason, the getElementsByClassName() always returns a node list with 0 elements.

The site I'm currently parsing is [here](http://szanhuzoalapitvany.hu/component/huskymentes/?act=3&task=details&cid=1206).

If you search for 'datas-nev', you will find exactly one match:

`<p class="datas-nev"><b>Kutya neve: </b>Jhonny</p>`

And here is the code use for parsing:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
...
final response = await http.get(URL);
var document = parse(response.body);
var detailsContainer = document.getElementById('husky_details_container_right');
var dogName = new List<Node>();
dogName = document.getElementsByClassName('datas-nev');
```

The contents of the detailsContainer can be extracted successfully, for example this gives me back a string of relevant data I will use later:

```
var humanBehaviourValue;
try { humanBehaviourValue = detailsContainer.nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[7].nodes[1].toString(); }
catch (e) { humanBehaviourValue = 'N/A'; }
```

But when I check the value of dogName in the debug window, I get the following:

`dogName = {_growableList} size = 0`

I already tried initializing the dogName 'properly' by `List<Node> dogName = new List<Node>();` but it didn't help. I also tried other datas-* values, but it seems the parser can't find them. I even tried using just datas (because that is a div, while others are paragraphs), but that didn't help either.

Basically I could just hardwire the name and some data (breed, color, etc) as those never really change, but the location of the shelter can change, and keeping it up-to-date by scraping the data seems better than pushing updates out manually. That means I mostly need the value of `datas-helyszin` but that isn't parsed either.

Comment: Where does `parse(...)` come from? How is this related to Flutter?

Comment: You are right, I forgot to include the import. Sorry.

Comment: `var dogName = new List<Node>();` creates an empty list, the next line replaces this empty list with the result. Before that 2nd line the size is supposed to be 0. I tried your code and for me the size is 1

Comment: Bah, I'm stupid... Thanks for the help. Now I'm gonna dig myself a nice hole :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Günter Zöchbauer pointed out, the code actually works. I was just looking for the value too soon, before it was actually fetched...